# When submitting a file on a form, it is not submitted

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have a problem for an university project where we have the creation of book registry. So far so good, however, we have a part for insertion of the book cover. Anyway tried, the file is not sent. I created a new directory to test and it also did not work. Follow the code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="index.php">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
<input type="file" name="cover"/>
<input type="submit" name="insert" class="btn btn-primary" value="Insert Data">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['insert'])):
    $destiny = '/' . $_FILES['cover']['name'];
    $tmp_file = $_FILES['cover']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file( $tmp_file, $destiny);
    var_dump($_FILES);
endif;
?>
```

When you click Submit without selecting any file, it falls into the IF normally. However, when submitting a file and clicking Submit, nothing happens. Only the page is reloaded. An attempt was made to put the correct $destiny and continue the same thing.

Edit:

I am receiving the following error:

> Warning: POST Content-Length of 3724451 bytes exceeds the limit of 3145728 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php what does that show?

Comment: $_FILES holds a lot of metadata regarding the file(s) that were uploaded, including an error code if things went wrong.  http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php  Also enable error reporting and/or logging and if anything shows up there please include it in the question.

Comment: As an aside, you seem to be trusting user input without any kind of validation.  This is a bad idea.  I could for example craft a POST that sets the file name to something like ../../../../../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd and trash your system (if /etc/passwd also happens to be world-writable)

Comment: @GordonM it's actually not my real project. I made a new folder just to test things and is that code above.

Comment: $destiny is an absolute path: starts with "/". You don't have permission to write in the root folder. move_uploaded_file returns a bool . You can also check it to see if the operation is successfull.

Comment: @Fred-ii- PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 3724451 bytes exceeds the limit of 3145728 bytes in Unknown on line 0 (in my C:\wamp\logs). Is that you want?

Comment: create a folder named files then change destiny to be `$destiny = 'files/' . $_FILES['cover']['name'];` as @fillipo have sugessted u dont have permission to write in the root folder

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Thanks @fillipo and @Masivuye and others for the help.

What I've done:

Changed the max size in php.ini, created the files folder inside index.php and also removed the max_size attribute from HTML. Working now!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="index.php">

<input type="file" name="cover"/>
<input type="submit" name="insert" class="btn btn-primary" value="Insert Data">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['insert'])):
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$destiny = $target_dir . basename($_FILES['cover']['name']);
$tmp_file = $_FILES['cover']['tmp_name'];
$uploadOk = 1;
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["cover"]["size"] > 30000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $destiny)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["cover"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}   

var_dump($_FILES);
endif;
?>
```